# Android Material Calendar Action Button Text not changing

Tags: android, material-components-android, samsung

I'm trying to use a MaterialDatePicker and customize the style of it.
I'm able to to mostly everything but for some reason in Samsung devices the positive button text doesn't change to what I want.

In strings.xml:

```
<string name="mtrl_picker_confirm" tools:override="true">APPLY</string>
```

And in styles I also have:

```
    <style name="MyCalendar" parent="ThemeOverlay.MaterialComponents.MaterialCalendar">
         <item name="buttonBarPositiveButtonStyle">@style/MyStyle.PositiveButtonStyle</item>
         <item name="buttonBarNegativeButtonStyle">@style/MyStyle.NegativeButtonStyle</item>
    </style>

    <style name="MyStyle.PositiveButtonStyle" parent="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.Button.TextButton.Dialog">
         <item name="android:textColor">@color/calendar_button_text</item>
         <item name="android:text">APPLY</item>
    </style>
```

This works fine in emulators but when I try the app in my Samsung the text is still displayed as OK.

Does anyone have any clue?
Thanks